# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) for API >22

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'll keep it short as possible. Got an app working properly on all API level 22 devices and under, but with the new versions above 22 that had the new implementations of rules regarding permissions, I get this error message trying to fetch a file, stating it cannot be found because I don't have the right permission.

Naturally, before asking, I've did some googling and found that people make this problem go away by making the targetSdkVersion in the 'uses-sdk' AndroidManifest tag set to 22. I did so, even added permissions inside the manifest, but I'm still getting this error.

Here's the whole manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.packagename.appname">

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22"></uses-sdk>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So what's the deal here?

I should mention that the app works flawlessly on the API 22 device and I've checked, the path of the file is the same, so to my best knowledge, it's a permission issue.

Comment: "making the targetSdkVersion in the 'uses-sdk' AndroidManifest tag set to 22" -- if you are developing using Android Studio, usually the `targetSdkVersion` is set in your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`). Moreover, the value in Gradle overrides the value in `<uses-sdk>`. Usually, we get rid of `<uses-sdk>` in the manifest and use Gradle for `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Make sure that your 22 is not being overridden by Gradle settings.

Comment: Again you come to my rescue. Spot on. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, `targetSdkVersion` was set via the `<uses-sdk>` element.

In Gradle-based Android app development, such as via Android Studio, the `targetSdkVersion` usually is set in the module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`). The value set in Gradle overrides the value set in the manifest.

As a result, adding `<uses-sdk>` to a manifest may not appear to have any effect, simply because Gradle is overriding the values.